# Closing or opening an Excel or Word file in Selenium IDE

Tags: excel, selenium, ms-word, ide

Testing a website that has links to various forms.  PDF forms work fine as long as I use the “goBackAndWait” command.  However if the document is a Word or Excel document, clicking the link opens the document in a new window (not a pop up window). Using the “close” command closes the main window and not the document window.

How to close or open the Excel or word file using Selenium IDE and go back to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the Selenium IDE **cannot** interact with embedded objects by default.

I can offer you an alternative.  Instead of opening the window, I recommend that you just check the URL of the links that you are clicking, and that the `href` points to the appropriate document extension.

Pseudo:

```
validatePresent  |  css=#doclink[href$='.docx']
```